# when you do decimals does the 0 go in front or back

Tags: decimal

when you are doing decimals does the 0 go in the front or back

Comment: Please clarify. I do not understand. Can you give more detail?

Comment: Sorry mate, can't answer this without some specifics. What language?

Comment: Also, what of the `[while-loops]` tag?  This question needs improving, front and back ;-)

Comment: belongs on ThisMustBeNewMath.com

Comment: The 0 can go both IN FRONT AND BACK! `double d = 09.0; // valid in Java`. It may not mean what you think it means, but I don't think you know what you think you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using C#, since that's the dominant language on this site.

Decimals aren't notated with a 0, rather they have the `M` suffix, eg:

```
decimal a = 123M;
decimal b = 123.456M;
float c = 123.456M; // compile error
```